# How do i load html from a db and display images that are stored locally in the project

Tags: c#, html, sql-server, model-view-controller, razor

I am storing the content for my page in a sql server database. When i load the content onto the page i have a tag:

`<img src="~/Images/Course/html.jpg" />`

The html is being rendered using `@Html.Raw(content).`

when the page loads i get the error:

`GET http://localhost:51249/Course/Index/~/Images/Course/html.jpg 404 (Not Found)`

I dont know why it does this. Is there any way to have images stored in files within the project, then when loading the html from the db the local linking works? Do I have to host the images somewhere and link to them via https? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it - just remove the tilda from the value in the database.  Here's a small sample code in the HTML to reproduce the same problem:

```
<img src="~/images/house.jpg" />

@{ 
    var something = "<img src='/images/house.jpg' />";
}

@Html.Raw(something)
```

The first line displays the image direct from the location, using the tilda, which .net resolves to the root of your project.

The second line doesn't use the tilda, which automatically comes from the root of the project, but leaving the tilda in messes up.

Fix: delete one character from the HTML stored in the database.